# Having to define mutators for nullable fields to avoid type errors

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a medium-large size system with Laravel. It has approximately 120 tables and maybe 70 of them have CRUDs. I have a problem with all these CRUDS. Every time I have nullable field that isn't of string type I have to define a mutator of this kind:

```
public function setCollectionIdAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['collection_id'] = $value ?: null;
}

public function setCompletedAtAttribute($value)
{ 
    $this->attributes['completed_at'] = $value ?: null;
}
```

I have to do this because in the front end the form fields aren't required so if a user doesn't fill the field the value that the backend receives are empty strings so when it tries to save this to the database type errors are thrown, so the functions I listed above check the values and set them to null.

Does Laravel provide a better way to do this? Because I have a lot of forms and its not cool having to define these functions every time I have a nullable field that isn't of string type.

Comment: Yes, its called default in MySQL (or any other database that is supported by Laravel).

Comment: The default value doesnt solve the problem. The problem is that Laravel tries to insert a an empty string ("") in fields of not-string type. Btw every time you define a nullable field it sets the default to null.

Comment: I see your struggle, use default values in MySQL and alter request data in way that if you have any empty string delete such attribute from array.

Comment: @Kyslik Might benefit you to look at the issue closer before posting a sarcastic comment.

Comment: Maybe it could be a way.. sending the request through some function that change empty string values to nulls.. I'll check if I can put it in some place that will be executed in every request so I havent to write it a lot of times

Comment: I am crafting an answer using trait so you can just apply trait and you are done. Or it can be done in middleware. I will write up both solutions up.

Comment: @Alan Have you checked out this package? https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-nullable-fields It works in a similiar way as Martin Bean's solution and is well documented and tested.

Answer (score 3):

I know the issue well and have encountered it many times before. For most projects, I create a `Nullable` trait that I apply to models. This trait looks for a `$nullable` property, loops over the attributes defined in that array, and set their values to `null` if they’re empty:

```php
trait Nullable
{
    public function bootNullable()
    {
        static::saving(function ($model) {
            foreach ((array) $model->nullable as $key) {
                if (empty($model->getAttribute($key))) {
                    $model->attributes[$key] = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You then just apply this trait to your models and define the `$nullable` property:

```php
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    use Nullable;

    protected $nullable = [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'baz',
    ];
}
```

Comment: brother, can you please explain me the cause of this issue. cos i have't faced this issue.

Comment: Its not an issue its an edge case, which you as coder have to solve.